# spring depenency injection with annotations

Tags: java, spring

I'm just starting with DI and Spring.  I have these two Components (pseudocode)

```
@Component
public class AuthHandlerImpl extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter implements AuthHandler {

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Override
    channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        authService.authenticate(msg);  // want to pass ctx to constructor of authService
    }
}

@Component
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthService {

    private CustomerService customerService;

    private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServiceImpl(CustomerService customerService, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is have AuthService injected with the constructor parameters, where one of the constructor arguments is the ChannelHandlerContext from the ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter class.  Not sure if that's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but CustomerService and ChannerHandlerContext must be defined as spring beans (like @Component, @Service, @Controller or @Bean annotations) in order to be autowired in the constructor. You can check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/) post to get more information about the topic.

Comment: so if ChannelHandlerContext is a third party framework type, is that still possible? And is it possible with annotations?

Comment: You can define a \@Configuration class. Inside you need to create a method with a particular annotation (\@Bean) that is in charge of return your third-party component.

\@Configuration
class MyConfigurationClass {
    \@Bean
    public getChannelHandlerContext() {
        return new ChannelHandlerConext(); //Now, the ChannelHandlerContext is a spring bean thanks to the \@Bean annotation.
    }
}